# How to animate the size change of an NSViewController presented as a sheet?

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

In Xcode, if you try to create a new file, it will ask you where to save it. There is this button that you can press to expand the sheet presented:

[image]

I am trying to create something similar to that button, which will enlarge an `NSViewController` presented with a Sheet segue. Note that I am not trying to create my own version of `NSSavePanel`. I am just trying to use this as an example to illustrate the behaviour of the button that I want to create.

I know that I can set the `preferredContentSize` to something bigger to enlarge the sheet:

```
preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
```

But that changes the size immediately, unlike the button in the save file dialog, which shows an animation of the sheet enlarging.

I tried putting it in an animation block:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
    context.duration = 1
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
}
```

But the same thing happens.

I'm pretty sure there should be a method in `NSViewController` or something like that I am failing to find...

Comment: I don't see how presenting a window sheet has anything to do with NSOpenPanel or NSSavePanel.

Comment: @ElTomato My question is not directly related to `NSSavePanel`. I am just trying to recreate the behaviour of a button in `NSSavePanel`, namely, enlarging the sheet with an animation.

Comment: There is a method for NSWindow: `self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true, animate: true)`

Comment: @Ckacmaster That's it! It worked! I never would have thought it would be in `NSWindow`, because I thought `view.window` refers to the actual window (with the three widgets on the top left and stuff), instead of the sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSWindow has a method to do exactly this:

```
self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), display: true, animate: true)
```

Comment: While applying this solution my window is sliding from top, but i want to reduce the size from bottom..
can u please tell me what can be the issue?

Comment: @hmali you may need to adjust your view constraints. Are you using NSSavePanel or a custom NSViewController for presentation?